# html save image button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an app that involves letting the user import and export photos.  I believe I have importing worked out fine using

```
<input type="file" />
```

but I cannot find a way to create an export button that functions in a similar way.  As in, it brings up the directory listing as lets the user choose where to save the picture that is currently being displayed.

Comment: an export would be a link or call to the server to serve up your file.

Comment: `<a href="downloadImage.php?img=pathtoimage">download image</a>` and have `downloadImage.php` return the image with the attachment header forcing a download.

Comment: You want a button that replicates the user "right-clicking" on the image and choosing "Save Image As"?

Comment: serve the file you want with mimetype `application/octet-stream` and then browser will be force to download.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly trigger a "Save as" dialog from a web application, but you can serve the image in a way that will make the browser do it.

You need to send the `Content-Type` (mime type) to [something like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type#Type_image) `image/jpeg` and `Content-Disposition` to something like `attachment; filename="fname.ext"`

As Kevin B suggested, you can accomplish this using PHP.  I don't think there's a way to do it with only JavaScript.

Comment: Alright its got to be done server-side, thanks to everyone that responded.